# Ruby on rails rails_admin with has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We are using `rails_admin` for manging our data on admin side.

We are facing an issue with `has_many` association, **its executing the query to fetch the details and along with it also executing one more query to get total count from that table.** i.e. see below queries.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE condition
```

Here's sample model.

```
has_many :users, :foreign_key => :user_id, :primary_key => :id

rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :users do
      label "Linked Users"
      inline_add false
    end
  end
end
```

**Can you please help me how can we avoid execution of second query.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be its default query from rails admin, for getting total record

Comment: Do you have any idea on how can we disable that option

Comment: Sorry, don't have idea how to disable it

Answer (score 0):

did not get you, you want to remove `field :users` from edit form?
if yes, you add

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    exclude_fields :users
  end
end
```

otherwise, you just want to disable `add user` from the form, the rails_admin still need to run those sql to fill `users combobox` on your form